# Silverlight 5 issue on mac

Tags: silverlight, macos, google-chrome

I'm experiencing problem with the SL 5 runtime for OS X (only tested on lion).
In all text boxes in our SL-app at work, the box get the focus when clicked. BUT, they do not accept any keyevents.

The cursor blinks but no inputs get through. Its possible to paste some text into the boxes, and then I notice that DELETE and BACKSPACE works.. very strange.

This only seems to be an issue on the runtime for mac on CHROME - not in safari and not in any browser on windows.

Can anyone op some light on this issue?
See this thread for more info: http://forums.silverlight.net/t/247149.aspx/1?Silverlight+5+issue+on+Mac

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its because Microsoft do not fully support some browsers on some OS. have a look at this

http://www.microsoft.com/getsilverlight/get-started/install/default.aspx#sysreq

Regards.

Comment: I actually have seen this before and kind of ignored it, because it worked perfectly for a long time in chrome when the application was built as Silverlight 4 project.
But I guess I'll have to accept this for now ..

Comment: I only use Chrome and I won't watch netflix on my mac because of this. It's 2012, not 1998; I shouldn't have to switch browsers for *anything* in a website.

Comment: agreed, but silverlight, flash and other fancy components are propriety of their owners, That is why i like open source. :)

Comment: The bug also appears on Safari 6.0

Answer (score 1):

This is a horrible hack but I've found that if you copy text from the clipboard into the text box it works.

Comment: sure it does! Its just like manually copy/paste some text into the textfield. The focusing works, its the actual input that doesn't.
.. horrible hack :)