# Cannot type into Silverlight 5 input fields (Chrome) MacOS

Tags: macos, google-chrome, silverlight-5.0

With Silverlight 5, I cannot type anything into the input fields. Using Chrome in MacOS.

Do I have to install a plugin or it is a specific configuration of the browser?

Comment: If you can see input fields made in Silverlight, you already have a working plugin.

Comment: Could you provide a not working demo?

Comment: Sadly, I'm starting to see this randomly on SL5.1 on Chrome 25.0 on Windows7. Randomly. On Chrome only.

Comment: www.freestockcharts.com still doesn't work.

Comment: I have this issue from the Azure management console. You can cut and paste into it but not type...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sadly this is the behavior of textboxes in Silverlight 5 in Chrome on osX. They work fine in Safari, Firefox, etc... but not Chrome.

Officially Silverlight is not supported in Chrome on osX.  Silverlight 4 worked fine, but 5 no.

Sorry that this is not the answer you're hoping for.

You can also look at this post:
[Silverlight 5 issue on mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9530750/silverlight-5-issue-on-mac)

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem and found a workaround: type the text in some other program, copy and paste it into silverlight.  For me it helped to type username and password into Lync Web App, which was enough.

I know this answer it late for original question, but it may help others who hit this thread like I did :-)

Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

If you are developing SL5 on Chrome for mac.   There is a work around, but it takes a little work.  Create a javascirpt function that captures key strokes, disable the default browser behavior for that keystroke and pass the key event to silverlight.  If a textfield is in focus, append the keyevent to the textfield.

It is not too hard to program up, but you need to keep in mind that not all keyevents are characters that you want to display.  Also, you need to do some bookkeeping in order to place the typed key in the correct location of a text field: as the cursor can move.